# OPA multiple default rules error when loaded into config-map

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, opa

I'm following [`OPA` deployment to `kubernetes` article](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/deployments/#kubernetes).
I try to load a different policy though, from the [`REGO` playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/). this is an official policy example so the syntax supposed to be impeccable.
Using the command:

```bash
kubectl create configmap example-policy --from-file example.rego
```

I load the `example.rego` file:

```
package app.rbac

import rego.v1

default allow := false

allow if user_is_admin

allow if {
    some grant in user_is_granted

    input.action == grant.action
    input.type == grant.type
}

user_is_admin if "admin" in data.user_roles[input.user]

user_is_granted contains grant if {
    some role in data.user_roles[input.user]

    some grant in data.role_grants[role]
}
```

and get the error from `opa` docker image:

```bash
example.rego:5: rego_type_error: multiple default rules data.app.rbac.allow found
```

The same file works when I run `OPA` as server on my local machine...
Any idea?